# Comparison of two zero values in disassembled code - unnecessary?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

Having disassembled an x86-64 executable, the disassembler shows the following instructions for a part of the executable.

```
xor r14d, r14d                      ; zero r14d
xor ecx, ecx                        ; zero ecx
mov qword [ss:rbp+var_40], rcx      ; move rcx (now zeroed) into var_40

; … additional code that doesn't make any changes to var_40 or r14d …

mov esi, r14d                       ; move r14d into esi
mov rcx, qword [ss:rbp+var_40]      ; move var_40 back into rcx
cmp rsi, rcx                        ; compare rsi and rcx, both zero?
```

It appears that `rsi` and `rcx` are being compared despite it being guaranteed that they are both zero. The code then branches following the comparison. Am I correct in thinking this and if so why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure the upper 32b of rcx are zero?

Comment: maybe to force some flags?

Comment: Maybe the code loops back later, by which time the values might have changed.

Comment: @Jester A good suggestion, looking into this now. Thanks!

Comment: With a debugger, set a breakpoint after the cmp, and watch the flags register (or `rsi` and `rcx`).  In gdb, `layout regs` makes this easy.  Just hit continue every time it triggers.  If there are any `nop`s in the "additional code", those are likely padding before branch targets (e.g. for a loop).

Comment: No: `rsi` is **not** guaranteed to be 0 since the code loaded `esi` but then compares `rsi`.

Comment: @WeatherVane that means the top is zero as well, or did you forget about the implicit zero-extension?

Comment: @harold I didn't know that so I just looked it up, thank you. Worked with 32 but not 64 bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, it looks like yours and Jester's suggestion figured this out. It appears that the code loops back at a later point but I hadn't noticed initially as it loops back prior to the location where the example begins.

Comment: @Joshua: if it loops back to before the snippet shown, then ISTM that R14 and RCX are zeroed again. Only if the code branches to a line that comes after the zeroing, this makes sense. Note that some not very well optimizing compilers do some unnecessary things multiple times, like re-reading a variable each time it is used.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Sorry, I meant that it loops back to a defined location in the 'additional code' that I hadn't included. Understood, thank you for the help.